# import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; not working

Tags: css, reactjs, computer-science, react-bootstrap, visual-web-developer

So basically i have a react application that i am creating and in it i have a page in which i am using the react-bootstrap library to create certain compnents.

Here i have a react regigtration form with bootstrap components and i have already installed all the libraries and this code works fine but the problem lies in the fact that when i run the page the styles dont show even though i have imported:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

So if there is any way this can be fixed please do let me know.

Thanks!

Here is the code for react page:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";


const UploadBussiness = () => {
return (
<Form>
  <Row className="mb-3">
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
      <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
      <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </Form.Group>
  </Row>

  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress1">
    <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control placeholder="1234 Main St" />
  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress2">
    <Form.Label>Address 2</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor" />
  </Form.Group>

  <Row className="mb-3">
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
      <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control />
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
      <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
      <Form.Select defaultValue="Choose...">
        <option>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </Form.Select>
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
      <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control />
    </Form.Group>
  </Row>

  <Form.Group className="mb-3" id="formGridCheckbox">
    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
  </Form.Group>

  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
    Submit
  </Button>
</Form>
  )
 }

export default UploadBussiness
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be other issues, but according to `react-bootstrap` [document](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css), perhaps try include this import in `App.js` instead of the component file:

> The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the new [React Docs (Beta)](https://beta.reactjs.org/) much more readable and helpful than the old [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). From the new [React Docs (Beta)](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn#adding-styles):

> React does not prescribe how you add CSS files. In the simplest case,
> you’ll add a `<link>` tag to your HTML. If you use a build tool or a framework, consult its documentation to learn how to add a CSS file to your project.

So what John Li says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74905554/15027348) is correct; he is directly quoting the React Bootstrap docs. However, you might also try adding the CSS directly to your HTML, which the [React Bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css) also recommends:

> How and which Bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the
> simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN. A little more information about the benefits of using a CDN can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp).

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

If this works, then you'll also have a version of Bootstrap specified, which might be helpful to you later.

EDIT: I forgot to emphasize that, as the React Docs (Beta) recommends, you should consult the docs of whatever build tool (e.g. [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)) or framework (e.g. [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/)) you are using. If you aren't using a build tool or a framework, you're sort of on your own.